# How Wikipedia renders infobox of a language different from English?

Tags: wikipedia, infobox

How Wikipedia renders information written in English template into another language?

For example, the viwiki page [Tokyo](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo) uses the English template [Template:Infobox Prefecture Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_Prefecture_Japan), but is displayed in Vietnamese.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help center]. You can also read about [ask] a good question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible! Every Wikipedia template is available only for the Wikipedia in which it is created. So, [Infobox Prefecture Japan](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q5620831) template is created separately in [enwiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_Prefecture_Japan) and in [viwiki](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E1%BA%A3n_m%E1%BA%ABu:Th%C3%B4ng_tin_t%E1%BB%89nh_Nh%E1%BA%ADt_B%E1%BA%A3n), but because viwiki template [Bản mẫu:Infobox Prefecture Japan](https://vi.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=B%E1%BA%A3n_m%E1%BA%ABu:Infobox_Prefecture_Japan&redirect=no) is redirected to the [Bản mẫu:Thông tin tỉnh Nhật Bản](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E1%BA%A3n_m%E1%BA%ABu:Th%C3%B4ng_tin_t%E1%BB%89nh_Nh%E1%BA%ADt_B%E1%BA%A3n), the information from **Thông tin tỉnh Nhật Bản** will be used when you call **Infobox Prefecture Japan** in some viwiki page.

Comment: @Terminija
Thanks for your answer.  
I checked the code, it is actually written in an English template. 
Please check it here [link](https://vi.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tokyo&action=edit). 

Moreover,  Bản mẫu:Thông tin tỉnh Nhật Bản is an empty template.

Also, Could you explain this case [Bản_mẫu:Infobox_Shinto_shrine](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E1%BA%A3n_m%E1%BA%ABu:Infobox_Shinto_shrine). There is an example in that page, the property is written in English but the display language is Vietnamese.

Comment: @YumiF, the language in which the template is written (including all properties) is without any sense, the important thing is the domain name. In your example **Tokyo** page is in viwiki (**vi.wikipedia.org**) and use **Infobox Prefecture Japan** template which redirect to **Thông tin tỉnh Nhật Bản** template, which is also in viwiki and it is NOT **empty template**! The same case is **Infobox Shinto shrine**.